# Is there any method to get the running docker container's startup arguments?

Tags: docker

Is there any method to get the running docker container's startup arguments? E.g.:

```
docker run -d -it --privileged --net=host --name oracle-net-host1 -v /oracle_data/oracle1:/data  mike/oracle12c:latest
```

I can get "`-d -it --privileged --net=host --name oracle-net-host1 -v /oracle_data/oracle1:/data  mike/oracle12c:latest`".

I have tried "`docker ps -a --no-trunc`", but it can't get arguments.

Comment: `history`? Your question is unclear though, do you want to get these from the container or from the host? Why not use bash variable?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one but you can query the individual parts using `docker inspect`.

```
docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks}}' oracle-net-host1
```

Gives something like this:

```
map[host:0xc876448c99]
```

Similarly

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Mounts}}' oracle-net-host1
```

would give

```
[{ /oracle_data/oracle1 /data local rprivate }]
```

I'm sure there are ways to make the output more friendly

Comment: How can I know which parameters are valid? E.g., `.Mounts` or `.NetworkSettings.Networks`. [Docker inspect command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) seems not provide this information.

Comment: The output of  `docker inspect oracle-net-host1` is json formatted. You should be able to figure out how to extract what you want from there.